# How do I conditionally select a field from one of two tables?

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables invoices and pending_payments both of which have the following rows in common: invoice_id and balance. I want to do a select in MySQL that'll work thus:

[pseudo-code]

```
if(invoice_id exists in pending_payments table) {
    select balance from pending_payments where invoice_id = yadayadayada
} else {
    select balance from invoices where invoice_id = yadayadayada
}
```

Is this even doable in MySQL? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select i.invoice_id, coalesce(pp.balance, i.balance) as Balance
from invoices i
left outer join pending_payments pp on i.invoice_id = pp.invoice_id
```

Let me know if there can be multiple rows in `pending_payments` for the same `invoice_id` and I will propose an alternate solution.

Comment: Wow, thanks OrbMan that was quick! Will give it shot in a bit and let you know how it works.

Comment: No, the invoice_id is unique and your solution worked, beautifully. Thanks! 
It appears you made a slight mistake though- the first value after the coalesce statement should be pp.balance. Not a criticism, mind you just a pointer to anyone else who might've run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like OrbMan's solution (I think it is the most intuitive), but here is another way -- select all from one table and then the ones that you have not selected from the 2nd.

```
select invoice_id, balance from pending_payments where invoice_id = yadayadayada
UNION
select invoice_id, balance from invoices where invoice_id = yadayadayada
  AND invoice_id not in (select invoice_id from pending_payments)
```

and as a side note, some have stated that on some systems this is actually faster.  I make no such claims, but if speed is an issue it is worth trying.

Also, if you need to include a source column (eg pending or invoice) it is easy to do it this way like this:

```
select 'pending' as source, invoice_id, balance from pending_payments where invoice_id = yadayadayada
UNION
select 'invoice' as source, invoice_id, balance from invoices where invoice_id = yadayadayada
  AND invoice_id not in (select invoice_id from pending_payments)
```

Comment: Much appreciated Hogan. Your solution is elegant in its simplicity. I tried it out too (without the source column as I didn't need it) just to make sure that it worked- and it did!

Comment: You're welcome.  It is always good to know more than one way to do things (and in SQL there always is more than one way to do something.)