# select from two tables and conditionally collapse one column

Tags: sql

I have a list of `Products`

```
upc | name     | price | qty
----------------------------
1   | apple    |  1.00 |  3
2   | peach    |  2.00 |  7
3   | melon    |  1.75 |  2
```

and `SaleProducts`

```
upc | price
------------
2   | 1.90
```

I want to select from Products but also sale price 
from SaleProducts (if product is on sale). This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT t1.upc, t1.name, MIN(t1.price) AS 'price', t1.qty
FROM (
  SELECT p.upc, p.name, p.price, p.qty
  FROM products p
    UNION
  SELECT sp.upc, NULL, sp.price, NULL
  FROM saleproducts sp
  ) t1
GROUP BY t1.upc;
```

Output:

```
upc | name     | price | qty
----------------------------
1   | apple    |  1.00 |  3
2   | peach    |  1.90 |  7
3   | melon    |  1.75 |  2
```

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way to accomplish this? Im aware of [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646007/how-do-i-conditionally-select-a-field-from-one-of-two-tables) but my goal is to grab whichever price is lower, so `COALESCE` wouldn't work.

The only restriction is, I must use vanilla SQL, no stored procs or IF's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead using `CASE`:

```
SELECT p.upc, p.name,
  CASE WHEN sp.price IS NOT NULL
    THEN CASE WHEN p.price > sp.price
      THEN sp.price
      ELSE p.price
    END
    ELSE p.price
  END price, p.qty
FROM products p LEFT JOIN saleproducts sp ON p.upc = sp.upc;
```

It will prefer to use the price from `saleproducts` when it's available.  If there is not a sale price for that product it will instead use the price from `products`.

**EDIT** - I've updated my answer so that it always gets the lowest price. FWIW I can't imagine why you'd bother having a sale price which is actually **higher than** your list price.

Comment: . . This is equivalent to `coalesce()` which the OP says won't work.

Comment: that's not plain SQL solution

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like the job for a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT p.upc, p.name,
       (case when sp.price is null or p.price < sp.upc  then p.price
             else sp.price
        end) as price,
       p.qty
FROM products p left outer join
     salesproducts sp
     on p.upc = sp.upc;
```